# Smarty - add html tag in foreach list

Tags: php

I have an encrypted script and I cannot modify the PHP files, just the HTML template files and I am trying to modify some pages.

What I want to do is to populate a list with some categories but after a certain number of categories I want to add an HTML tag. I have this option in admin panel but for videos not for categories. For videos i have this code:

```
            {foreach from=$array_recently_added_videos item=video name=videos}
<div class="video">
html code here..
</div>

        {if ($smarty.foreach.videos.index+1)%$aSettings.videos_cols==0}<br class="clear">{/if}
        {foreachelse}
          <center><br><b>No videos where found.</b><br></center>
        {/foreach}
```

So if i set in admin panel, 5 columns of videos. After 5 videos it ads this piece of html code

```
<br class="clear">
```

I want to do the same with the categories. And here im lost. Here is the code i have.

```
{foreach from=$array_groups[$group_id] item=categ name=categs}

                                  <input type='checkbox' name='{$categ.category_id}' value='{$categ.category_id}'  id='{$categ.category_id}' ><label for='{$categ.category_id}' >{$categ.category_name}</label><br>

        {if ($smarty.foreach.categs.index+1)%$aSettings.videos_cols==0}</td><td valign='top' align='left'>{/if}               

{/foreach}
```

It adds this piece of HTML code `</td><td valign='top' align='left'>` after 5 categories but I want to add a custom number for categories not the number set for videos. I do not know with what to change this code `%$aSettings.videos_cols==0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change,

```
    {if ($smarty.foreach.categs.index+1)%$aSettings.videos_cols==0}</td><td valign='top' align='left'>{/if}
```

to

```
    {if ($smarty.foreach.categs.index+1)%5==0}</td><td valign='top' align='left'>{/if}
```

Just change the number 5.